# Set password for PDF file in IOS

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation

How do i set password for PDF file while generating So the user open the file with password after downloading it from Email?any help will be appriecaited.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, CFSTR("My PDF File"));
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("My Name"));
///
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextUserPassword, CFSTR("userpassword"));
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, CFSTR("ownerpassword"));
///
pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url, &pageRect, myDictionary);
```

Check this [Creating Password Protected PDF in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598005/creating-password-protected-pdf-in-objective-c)